# How to create Oracle Spatial Index?

Tags: oracle, spatial, oracle-spatial

I am trying to create an Oracle Spatial index but seeing strange behavior.

I have a table in my schema as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "Event" (  
"EventID" NUMBER(32,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOT NULL, 
    "Name" NVARCHAR2(30), 
    "Location" "SDO_GEOMETRY" NOT NULL, 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_EVENT" PRIMARY KEY ("EventID")
   ) ;
```

This works fine and I know I have to create an entry in user_sdo_geom_metadata, that works as you would expect with the following:

```
insert into user_sdo_geom_metadata (table_name,column_name,diminfo,srid) values ('Event','Location', 
sdo_dim_array(sdo_dim_element('X',-180.0,180.0, 0.005),sdo_dim_element('Y',-90.0,90.0, 0.005)), 4326);
```

This reports success and when I do a select on user_sdo_geom_metadata I see the row. However, when I try to create the spatial index with:

```
CREATE INDEX "EVINDEX" ON "Event" ("Location") INDEXTYPE IS MDSYS.SPATIAL_INDEX_V2
```

I get the following error:

```
SQL Error [29855] [99999]: ORA-29855: error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine
ORA-13203: failed to read USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA view
ORA-13203: failed to read USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA view
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_INDEX_METHOD_10I", line 10
```

The weird thing is the Index looks like it's been created.

```
select * from all_indexes where table_name='Event';
```

Shows the index??? The other odd thing is when I do a select * on ALL_SDO_GEOM_METADATA, no rows are returned??? I'm connecting as a user with almost every privilege and role but not as SYSDBA. I can't get my head around this one.

**UPDATE**

Incredibly, this seems to be a case sensitivity issue. If you change the table and column names to all UPPERCASE it works. It seems my neverending disappointment in Oracle has a whole new chapter. Going to try to struggle through this somehow, but like most things with Oracle, it's one unrelenting slog to get anything done :(

Comment: Why are you using quoted identifiers? It is bad practice to use them and it means you have to use the correct case everywhere they are used. Just use unquoted identifiers, and Oracle will implicitly convert the unquoted identifier to upper-case which means that you can use any case in your queries.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, this is just a boiled-down example. In the real code, I can't control the names of tables or columns. This means that I can't create a table with a geospatial column unless it follows the naming conventions for non-quoted identifiers. Or more accurately, it's a defect that Oracle hasn't fixed.

Comment: Also, the fact that the index, kinda seems to get created anyway, maybe. All kinds of broken :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/spatl/spatial-datatypes-metadata.html#GUID-AEA8FA01-880B-4865-8074-3B6FBD17A5E1) says:

> The table name cannot contain spaces or mixed-case letters in a quoted string when inserted into the USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA view, and it cannot be in a quoted string when used in a query (unless it is in all uppercase characters).

and

> The column name cannot contain spaces or mixed-case letters in a quoted string when inserted into the USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA view, and it cannot be in a quoted string when used in a query (unless it is in all uppercase characters).

However, it also says:

> All letters in the names are converted to uppercase before the names are stored in geometry metadata views or before the tables are accessed. This conversion also applies to any schema name specified with the table name.

which you can see if you query the `user_sdo_geom_metadata` view after your insert; the mixed-case names have become uppercase `EVENT` and `LOCATION`.

But then:

> Note: Letter case conversion does not apply if you use mixed case (“CamelCase”) names enclosed in quotation marks. However, be aware that many experts [recommend against using mixed-case names](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9525305800346887676).

And indeed, rather unintuitively, it seems to work if you include the quotes in the `user_sdo_geom_metadata` insert:

```
insert into user_sdo_geom_metadata (table_name,column_name,diminfo,srid)
values (
  '"Event"',
  '"Location"', 
  sdo_dim_array(sdo_dim_element('X',-180.0,180.0, 0.005),
  sdo_dim_element('Y',-90.0,90.0, 0.005)), 4326
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LkDPPayp)

So it appears that the values from the view are at some point concatenated into a dynamic SQL statement, which would explain some of the behaviour.

Comment: Awesome, this does work!!!! Remarkable but it does. Now I need to get it working for a schema that's not the current user's but that's a battle for another day!!! Thank you.